# React Component not updating even after duplication of state in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state

## Context

The goal is to have a component with a key name being react-rendered in App.js when I press a specific key, registered in another component. The information is being passed thorugh a redux managed state.

## The problem

It's simple :
I'm updating my state in my redux reducer but even when duplicating it (I can see it thanks to the redux dev tool that allows me to watch my prevState and my nextState being different)

And the question is as simple :

> Why my App.js component won't re-render even after connecting to and
> duplicating my state ?

I think I made sure that my state was duplicated with the spreading operation and my redux dev tool display me a good state update without having my prevState and nextState duplicated. I looked through a lot of posts and found only people that forgot to duplicate their state in their reducers, which I did not.
So what's the problem here ??

## DevTool Sample

[image]

## Code

Here is the code, quite simple. The interesting piece is **playSound** and **playedKeys**:

### App.js :

```js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import KeyComponent from './Components/Key'
import SoundPlayer from './Components/Sounds'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...state.soundReducer
 })

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      {console.log(this.props)}
        {
          this.props.playedKeys.map(key =>{
            <KeyComponent keyCode={key}>  </KeyComponent>
          })
        }
        <SoundPlayer></SoundPlayer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

### Reducer

```js
export default (state = {allSounds:{},playedKeys:[]}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_SOUND':
      return reduce_addSound({...state},action)
    case 'PLAY_SOUND':
      return reduce_playSound({...state,playedKeys : [...state.playedKeys]},action)
    
    default:
    return state
  }
}
  
function reduce_addSound (state,action){

  let i = 0
  state.allSounds[action.payload.key] = { players : new Array(5).fill('').map(()=>(new Audio())) , reader : new FileReader()}

  //load audioFile in audio player
    state.allSounds[action.payload.key].reader.onload = function(e) {
      state.allSounds[action.payload.key].players.forEach(player =>{
        player.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        player.load();
        player.id = 'test'+e.target.result+ i++ 
      })
  }
  state.allSounds[action.payload.key].reader.readAsDataURL(action.payload.input.files[0]);
  
  return state
}

function reduce_playSound(state,action){

  state.playedKey = action.payload.key;

  if(!state.playedKeys.includes(state.playedKey))
    state.playedKeys.push(action.payload.key);

  return state
}
```

### Action

```js
export const addSound = (key, input,player) => (dispatch,getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_SOUND',
        payload: {key : key, input : input}
       })
   }
   
export const playSound = (key) => (dispatch,getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'PLAY_SOUND',
        payload: {key : key}
       })
   }
```

### The component registering the keypresses

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { playSound } from '../../Actions/soundActions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...state.soundReducer
 })

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    playSound: (keyCode) => dispatch(playSound(keyCode))
 })

 class SoundPlayer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        this.playSoundComponent = this.playSoundComponent.bind(this)
        document.body.addEventListener('keypress', this.playSoundComponent);
    }

    keyCodePlayingIndex = {};

    playSoundComponent(key){
        if(this.props.allSounds.hasOwnProperty(key.code)){

            if(!this.keyCodePlayingIndex.hasOwnProperty(key.code))
                this.keyCodePlayingIndex[key.code] = 0

            this.props.allSounds[key.code].players[this.keyCodePlayingIndex[key.code]].play()

            this.keyCodePlayingIndex[key.code] = this.keyCodePlayingIndex[key.code] + 1 >= this.props.allSounds[key.code].players.length ? 0 : this.keyCodePlayingIndex[key.code] + 1
            console.log(this.keyCodePlayingIndex[key.code])
        }

        this.props.playSound(key.code);
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            <h1 >Played : {this.props.playedKey}</h1>
            {Object.keys(this.keyCodePlayingIndex).map(key =>{
                return <p>{key} : {this.keyCodePlayingIndex[key]}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SoundPlayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've got it, it's always the simplest stupidest thing that we don't check huh.

## Clarification

So my state was properly duplicated with `reduce_addSound({ ...state },action)` and `reduce_playSound({ ...state, playedKeys: [...state.playedKeys]` and like I wrote in my question, that wasn't the issue !

## Issue

As old as it can get, I wasn't returning a component in my render function.. :

in App.js :

```js
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.soundReducer.playedKeys.map(key =>{
            <KeyComponent keyCode={key}>  </KeyComponent> //<-- NO return or parenthesis !!
          })
        }
        <SoundPlayer></SoundPlayer>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

## Answer

App.js render function with parenthesis:

```js
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.soundReducer.playedKeys.map(key =>(
            <KeyComponent key = {key} keyCode={key}>  </KeyComponent> //<-- Here a component is returned..
          ))
        }
        <SoundPlayer></SoundPlayer>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You are mutating your state object.

- `state.allSounds[action.payload.key] = ...`
- `state.playedKey = action.payload.key;`

## Solution

Update your reducer functions to return new `state` objects, remembering to correctly shallow copy each level of depth that is being updated.

```
export default (state = { allSounds: {}, playedKeys: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_SOUND':
      return reduce_addSound({ ...state },action);

    case 'PLAY_SOUND':
      return reduce_playSound({ ...state, playedKeys: [...state.playedKeys] }, action);
    
    default:
    return state
  }
}
  
function reduce_addSound (state, action) {
  const newState = {
    ...state,  // shallow copy existing state
    allSounds: {
      ...state.allSounds, // shallow copy existing allSounds
      [action.payload.key]: {
        players: new Array(5).fill('').map(()=>(new Audio())),
        reader: new FileReader(),
      },
    }
  };

  // load audioFile in audio player
  newState.allSounds[action.payload.key].reader.onload = function(e) {
    newState.allSounds[action.payload.key].players.forEach((player, i) => {
      player.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
      player.load();
      player.id = 'test' + e.target.result + i // <-- use index from forEach loop
    })
  }
  newState.allSounds[action.payload.key]
    .reader
    .readAsDataURL(action.payload.input.files[0]);
  
  return newState;
}

function reduce_playSound (state, action) {
  const newState = {
    ...state,
    playedKey: action.payload.key,
  };

  if(!newState.playedKeys.includes(newState.playedKey))
    newState.playedKeys = [...newState.playedKeys, action.payload.key];

  return newState
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer, I tried your method (thank you for the addition of the index of each loop ;) ) but sadly it didn't change my behaviour..


So if I understand correctly, the moment I use `reduce_addSound({ ...state },action)`  and `reduce_playSound({ ...state, playedKeys: [...state.playedKeys] }`, I'm not copying the entirety of my object ? 

Thus having to shallow copy every level of my object in my reducer ? 

Because it seems that it's not enough if the problem is the mutation of the reducer.

Comment: If you're interested in checking out the full code and find that it doesn't change the behaviour, here is the link with the current branch : https://github.com/pazka/my-custom-soundboard/tree/dynamic-keys/src. 

You just have to do the classic checkout / npm i / npm start

Comment: @Pazka Oops, yeah, that *does* copy the state object, but you weren't necessarily copying the more deeply nested state. Nice catch, thanks.

Comment: No problem, it was instructive anyway, thank you for your time !